# How to send AuthenticateResult.Fail(failure reason), failure reason to to Response body

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fiddler

In my ASP.NET Core WebAPI application, I used the custom Authentication middleware to authenticate the request. Everything is working fine, but I am not getting how Failure reason will send to user in response object.

```
    protected override  Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
    var token = headers["Authorization"].ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
    return  Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Token is null"));
    
    }

}
```

I have tried:

```
Task callTask = Task.Run(
                    async () => await Context.Response.WriteAsync(errorResult).ConfigureAwait(false));


                if (callTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    callTask.Wait();
                }
```

But getting 504 status code in fiddler

> [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 379 bytes.

How this failure reason "Token is null" will send to response.

Comment: What did fiddler say the server returned (raw headers and body)?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure Content-Type: text/html;  Connection: close [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 379 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware for customising unauthorized response body. You put it between `UseRouting` and `UseAuth*` calls in Startup.cs

```cs
// Your Configure method in Startup.cs

app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("some custom message");
    }
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The middleware passes request to the next handler, awaits it, then checks for response code and if it's 401, modifies response body. *Don't forget about setting response content type, it's important here*.

Basically, you can place any logic here. For example, in authentication handler you can set custom response header with unauthorized reason:

```cs
Response.Headers.Add("X-Custom-Unathorized-Reason", "...");
```

and then access this message in middleware:

```cs
var reason = context.Response.Headers["X-Custom-Unathorized-Reason"];
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
await context.Response.WriteAsync(reason);
```

Comment: There's also a [modern way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to do this via `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler`. But it works only in .NET 5/6